# Excel Formula to calculate Specific amount

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to give a scheme for every 6 purchased items.

let's suppose if a customer purchase 6 items and I select 6+1 in G2 dropdown the price should be of 6 items while in E2 it should be incremented to 7.

If another customer asks for 8 items, the amount should be 810 if the scheme applied to 6+1 customer will get 7 items instead of 6 in amount of 6, while the remaining 1 item should be costed standard price like. 135 (F2) 6+1 will be reduced to price 115.71 instead of 135

135x6=810 +1 free (7 items) , 810+135=945 customer will get discount of 270.

```
 B       C         D       E        F       G        H

| 1 | Products  | Sale | Total  | Price | Scheme | Amount |

| 2 | Product 1 | 6    | 7      | 135   | 6+1    | 945    |

| 3 | Product 2 | 8    | 7      | 135   |        | 1080   |
```

Now if I add 17 Items in the sale, every 6 items (2 times in this example) will be charged with rate 115.71, while remaining 5 items will be charged as 135 (If I apply scheme in G2, otherwise the standard rate of 135 will be applied to 6,8 12 or whatever numbers)

home this helps

PS I've added formula in E2 o determine whether the scheme is applied in G1

=IF(G2="",D$2,IF(G5="6+1",D$2+1))
and =IF(G2="6+1",E2*F2,IF(G2="",D2*F2)) in Amount (H2) cell reference may vary in this example.

Thanks

Comment: Your post is a little difficult to understand. Are you saying that if you select the scheme, the customer will receive 1 extra item for every 6 items they purchase? So, if the customer purchases 6 items, he will get 1 extra and will get 7 in total, but only pay for 6? Similarly, if he purchases 15 items, he will get 17 total, but only pay for 15?

Comment: Of course, you got my point because in 15 items the 6 will repeat two times e.g 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have understood this post as:

I apply a scheme to a purchase which assigns free item(s) to each multiple of items purchased. The amount paid is only for the number of items purchased.

[image]

In this image, I enter a product - the product name, the sale and the price. Then I select (or don't select) a scheme for the sale.

The scheme takes the format {integer}+{integer}. First, the scheme is broken into its component parts. The **Threshold** at which the free item(s) are received (which is the number to the left of the + sign):

```
=IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT([@[Scheme ]],FIND("+",[@[Scheme ]])-1)),"")
```

The number of items **FreePerThreshold** (which is the number to the right of the + sign):

```
=IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID([@[Scheme ]],FIND("+",[@[Scheme ]])+1,LEN([@[Scheme ]]))),"")
```

The **Multiples** of the threshold in the current sale, which is the number of times the threshold has been met by the items purchased:

```
=IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN([@[Sale ]]/[@Threshold],0),"")
```

The number of **Free items**, which is the multiples times the free per threshold if a scheme is selected, or zero otherwise:

```
=IFERROR([@FreePerThreshold]*[@Multiples],0)
```

The **Amount Paid** is always just the Sale times the Price:

```
=[@[Sale ]]*[@[Price ]]
```

The **Total Amount** is the theoretical amount that would've been paid if the items weren't free:

```
=[@[Total  ]]*[@[Price ]]
```

And finally, the **Discount Received** is the Total Amount minus the Amount Paid:

```
=[@[Total Amount]]-[@[Amount Paid]]
```

Comment: You're a Champ!, this worked perfectly, thanks a lot God bless you

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. If this has helped, please consider up-voting and accepting my answer.